# How do you change the resize increment?

Tags: compiz, window-manager, metacity, window

I currently have my

`<distance name = "left/right/bottom/whatever_width" value = 0\>`

so I have to use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F8</kbd> to resize windows.  Unfortunately, this is a bit cumbersome because the resize increment is so large.  I'd like to change it so that when using keybindings to resize a window, the window only changes by a few pixels per "click".

I haven't been able to find any information on this issue.

Is it even possible to do this?

Comment: What does that cryptic semi-XML snippet *mean*?

Answer (score 1):

Looking into both Compiz and Metacity, both provide the functionality of pressing Alt+F8 to begin resize and you can change the bindings or disable it; but both fail to provide any configuration option for the degree of change when pressing the keyboard cursor keys.

I fear that the answer would have to depend on first which you're using (classic, compiz or new qt based compatibility mode) and secondly if you're willing to go ask the developers of the relevant project to look through their code. My best guess, they don't even know anyone wants to change the degree.